# Play Framework - How to export runtime working folder from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, playframework

I am working in a Project using Play Framework 2.2.x. After executing `play dist` to get the package ready, I place it in some folder like `/home/project1/`, and navigate to `/home/project1/bin` to run the Linux script file and start the project.

My question here - is there we can modify the `dist` task of Play, so I can update the Linux script file to export the current working folder (in this case `/home/project1/`) so I can refer to in the source code? Or is there any additional runtime parameters we can pass to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if with source code you mean the Play code, you can get the application path with [`application.path()`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/Application.html#path())

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it correctly on Linux. Unfortunately, on Windows when I run the `project1.bat` in `bin` folder, the application().path() return the `bin` folder location, not the application folder as on Linux.

I also found that the `project1.bat` exports a variable named `PROJECT1_HOME` at the application folder, I can use System.getenv() to retrieve it. However the bash script on Linux doesn't export that variable, so I want to export that `PROJECT1_HOME` as in Windows

Comment: Well, i am not able to understand your question correctly. But few links i want to share that may help you 1. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist#the-native-packager. And  http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#change-remove-top-level-directory-in-output

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't express my idea clearly, but in general I would like to do some modifications to the `dist` task of Play to include some additional things. Looks like the links you provided should be a good starting point to look at. Thanks a lot.